# Bootstrap 3 - 2 rows beside each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I got a problem with bootstrap 3. I want to have 2 rows beside each other when it comes to large screens. I used 2 rows because when it comes to smaller screens they need to be underneath each other. When it comes to mobile they need to be with just 1 row. But that's not really important for my question.

[So this picture shows how it looks vs how it is supposed to look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ufb3H.png)

```
<div class="icons"> <!-- icons -->
        <div class="row"><!-- row -->

            <!--Begin van 1e rij-->
                <div class="row"> <!-- row1 -->
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-0" style="border: 3px solid black;background-color:grey;">
                        <img src="img/pakketten_images/Pakket_kar.png"> <br>
                        <span class="span3-1">Onlineshop</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-3 col-md-offset-0 col-lg-2" style="border: 3px solid black;background-color:grey;">
                        <img src="img/pakketten_images/Pakket_card.png"> <br>
                        <span class="span3">Met betaalfuncties</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-3 col-md-offset-0 col-lg-2" style="border: 3px solid black;background-color:grey;">
                        <img src="img/pakketten_images/Pakket_chat.png"> <br>
                        <span class="span3">Online klantcontact</span>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- /row1 -->

            <!--Begin van 2e rij-->
                <div class="row"> <!-- row2 -->
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-0" style="border: 3px solid black;background-color:grey;">
                        <img src="img/pakketten_images/Pakket_koppel.png"> <br>
                        <span class="span3">Webshop koppelen</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-3 col-md-offset-0 col-lg-2" style="border: 3px solid black;background-color:grey;">
                        <img src="img/pakketten_images/Pakket_search.png"> <br>
                        <span class="span3">Verhoogt vindbaarheid</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-3 col-md-offset-0 col-lg-2" style="border: 3px solid black;background-color:grey;">
                        <img src="img/pakketten_images/Pakket_marketing.png"> <br>
                        <span class="span3">Internet marketing</span>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- /row2 -->

            </div> <!-- row -->
        </div> <!-- /icons -->
```

Comment: Use`cols` instead of `rows` and use the relevant `col-xs-X` and `col-md-X` classes

Comment: a row class will do that. It will separate into 2 different rows hence the name **row** a better approach would be to have all the content in 1 row and use col-sm-12 parent div with content wrapped inside as col-sm-3

Comment: So I just remove the `row` classes and change `col-xs-0` to `col-xs-X`?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to have multiple rows, you can combine them and it will wrap automatically as you fill out the space. Your markup is very close - If I'm understanding what you're trying to achieve, you should be able to just remove the inner rows and leave the rest of your markup unchanged:

```
<div class="icons"> <!-- icons -->
        <div class="row"><!-- row -->

            <!--Begin van 1e rij-->
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-0" style="border: 3px solid black;background-color:grey;">
                <img src="img/pakketten_images/Pakket_kar.png"> <br>
                <span class="span3-1">Onlineshop</span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-3 col-md-offset-0 col-lg-2" style="border: 3px solid black;background-color:grey;">
                <img src="img/pakketten_images/Pakket_card.png"> <br>
                <span class="span3">Met betaalfuncties</span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-3 col-md-offset-0 col-lg-2" style="border: 3px solid black;background-color:grey;">
                <img src="img/pakketten_images/Pakket_chat.png"> <br>
                <span class="span3">Online klantcontact</span>
            </div>

    <!--Begin van 2e rij-->
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-0" style="border: 3px solid black;background-color:grey;">
                <img src="img/pakketten_images/Pakket_koppel.png"> <br>
                <span class="span3">Webshop koppelen</span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-3 col-md-offset-0 col-lg-2" style="border: 3px solid black;background-color:grey;">
                <img src="img/pakketten_images/Pakket_search.png"> <br>
                <span class="span3">Verhoogt vindbaarheid</span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-3 col-md-offset-0 col-lg-2" style="border: 3px solid black;background-color:grey;">
                <img src="img/pakketten_images/Pakket_marketing.png"> <br>
                <span class="span3">Internet marketing</span>
            </div>
            </div> <!-- row -->
        </div>
</div>
```

See codepen: https://codepen.io/kball/pen/VMwMyo?editors=1010